# Handling exception with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am parsing several individual pages with BeautifulSoup.

Several pages get parsed and it gets to a point, on a specific site, that the parsing fails.

I am looking to extract the following tag:

```
<span class="black20b">$27.99</span>
```

I use the following selector to get the tag. As a matter of fact, I tried two different ones and got the same results:

```
price = individual_page.find("span", {"class","black20b"})
price = ''.join(price.findAll(text=True))
```

I decided to print the outcome of price BEFORE the join is executed, on several files and this is the outcome:

```
...
Downloading: File...
<span class="black20b">$7.79</span>

Downloading: File...
<span class="black20b">$27.99</span>

Downloading: File...
None
```

The last selector returns "None". 
Checking on that specific case, it turns out that span is coloured differently for some specific reasons. In other words, that tag does not exist.

How can I handle that exception?

Comment: What are the possibilities of other class names? Because regex is probably the solution here

Comment: The class can be, in this case at least, black20b or red13b. Is it possible to handle that somehow? 

Or is it possible to tell it, if it returns NONE, to not do anything?

Comment: Well, to make it not print the `None`s, just add: `matching = individual_page.find("span", {"class","black20b"}) ; if matching: price = matching` or something similar

Comment: Its not the print what I dont need to do, its to call the function but I saw what you mean. Will try it now, thanks! Put it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Question: Is this within a for loop :3?

Comment: No. I just had to verify with ''if matching:'' and it worked. In some cases there is just no data to extract so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid calling the function if the result is None:

```
price = individual_page.find("span", {"class","black20b"})
if price:
    print ''.join(price.findAll(text=True))
```